# How can I ignore self-signed certificate warning using fetch() javascript with Node ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, express, self-signed

I have a client-side server running with NodeJS and ExpressJS, and it makes API calls to the back-end API server. But the back-end API server throws a self-signed certificate error warning whenever the API call is made with `fetch()`.

How can I ignore the self-signed certificate warning and make the browser to trust the back-end API server at all times to make the API calls?

Here is the error:

[image]

And here is how I make the API call using fetch:

```
  logInUser(userCredentials) {

    var userCredsBody = {
        'firstname': `${userCredentials.username}`,
        'password': `${userCredentials.password}`
    }

    var configuration = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(userCredsBody)
    }

    return function(dispatch) {
      fetch('https://serverapi.com:8080/userInfo', configuration)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Successful and ', response)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error: ", error)
      })
    }
```

And here is how my client-side NodeJS and ExpressJS is set up:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var cors = require('cors');
    var path = require('path');
    var config = require('../webpack.config.js');
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
    var webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
    var app = express();
    var compiler = webpack(config);

    app.use(cors());

    app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath}));

    app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

    app.use(express.static('./dist'));

    app.use('/', function (req, res) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'))
    })

    var port = 3000;

    app.listen(port, function(error) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log("Express server listening on port", port);
    });
```